# Printing lines after identifying the start and end xml tags, including the tags too, through a XML file

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to parse a "pseudo" XML file, identifying the start and end "tags" and print the tags + the text in between and repeat it through the entire XML file

Here a sample of the "pseudo" XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<config lastObjectId='4414'>
    <Agent Host='us.com'
        User='PLCR1'
        lastModifiedDate='2014-08-01'>
    </Agent>
</config>
```

1. The start tag to identify is `"<Agent Host='us.com'"`
2. The end tag to identify is `"</Agent>"`

I have tried different Regex to match the entire block, however those are strict / fixed to the amount of lines that the XML block contains and it's not good enough yet.

Note: I say is a pseudo XML as all of the `<Agent Host='us.com'` are formatted that way, without the `" > "`

Regex

```
(.*Agent.*)((.*\n){1,3})(.*Agent.*)
```

Then I tried using "re.match" but I haven't found the way to combine the if statement to meet the start and end tag.

Basically I'd say my problem is on the if statement and regex.

```
import re
xmlfile = open("20190211", "r")
output = open("output1.txt", "w")
counter = 0
for line in xmlfile:
    if re.match(".*Agent.*us.*",line):
        print (line , file = output)
        counter += 1
print ("Count: %s"% (counter) ,file =output)
output.close()
```

I would expect to match and print on a file the XML "block" identified by start and end tag.

```
<Agent Host='us.com'
    User='PLCR1'
    lastModifiedDate='2014-08-01'>
</Agent>
```

And then go through the rest of the file and find some others..

Comment: Why not use a xml parser instead?

Comment: Exactly, you can parse the xml code like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: Oh I've already explored that possibility too but is not useful for the end use i will give as this output structure will be used for other python scripts. 
On the other hand the XML used as input file has many formatting errors as tags not terminated with " > " as I highlighted in the description.

Comment: It's not a duplicate issue as when you use ElementTree your input XML formatting should be OK, and it's not the case here.
A different approach should be followed here to overcome from a bad formatting XML file as input .

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of extra tries I came with the answer to my question.
Adding the second "for loop" will search and match the end tag and do the same through all the XML input file in case it matchs both tags

```
start tag -->>>>   <Agent Host='us.com'
end tag   -->>>>   </Agent>
```

```
import re
xmlfile = open("20190211", "r")
output = open("output1.txt", "w")
counter = 0
for line in xmlfile:
    if re.match(".*Agent.*us.*",line):
        print (line , file = output)
        counter += 1

    for line in xmlfile:
        print (line ,file = output)
        if re.match(".*Agent>,line):
            break
print ("Count: %s"% (counter) ,file =output)
output.close()
```